# Whats the precedence and associativity of f x? Haskell

Tags: haskell, associative, operator-precedence

I know that . and $ both have right associativity, so that

```
f . g . x
```

would be

```
f . (g . x)
```

I also know that . has precedence over most, such that

```
f . x + 5 * 4
```

would be

```
f . ((x + 5) * 4)
```

but when you have just

```
f g x
```

whats the associativity and precedence?

Comment: the associativity of `f g x` is left to right because of currying, `f` takes one parameter, and returns a function that takes one parameter. `let k = f g` followed by `k x` is the exact same as doing `(f g) x` or simply just `f g x`

Comment: Function compostion,`.` , has fixity and precedence `infixr 9`. `9` is the [highest possible precedence](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.2), but other operators, including `!!`, have the same precedence. Function application by juxtaposition such as `f x` also has higher precedence than function composition with `.`, so `.` does not have "precedence over all".

Comment: `.` has the highest fixity declarable, yes, but that means `f . x + 5 * 4` is parsed as `(f . x) + (5 * 4)`, not `f . (x + (5 * 4))`. (Or even `f . ((x + 5) * 4)` – how did you get that idea?)

Comment: @leftaroundabout could you explain why? I used a precedence table

Comment: Yes – your order of precedence is right, but I think you misunderstand what precedence _means_. If you have `infixl 6 +` and higher `infixl 7 *`, then `*` gets imaginary parens around it before `+` is considered, i.e. `a + b * c` is parsed as `a + (b * c)`, not `(a + b) * c`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Okay, thanks for the help! How does left/right associativity work?

Comment: Associativity only matters when you have two operators with the same fixity in a chain. For instance, the sum `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`; this is parsed with more parens on the left (hence the `l` in `infixl 6 +`), i.e. as `((1 + 2) + 3) + 4`. OTOH, `1 : 2 : 3 : []` is parsed as `1 : (2 : (3 : []))`, because the fixity is `infixr 5 :`.

Comment: Note that the precedence of `(.)` over itself doesn't matter because `f . (g . a)` is equal to `(f . g) . a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function application associates to the left, so

```
f g x
```

is the same as

```
(f g) x
```

Comment: I always remember Roger Hindley saying "Function application associates to the left, rather as we all did in the sixties.".

Comment: Function application always has the highest precedence.